# How to get values of multiple dropdowns and file uploads appended with Jquery Multifield plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get the values of multiple select boxes and file inputs using jquery.
I am using [Jquery Multifield plugin](http://maxkostinevich.github.io/jquery-multifield/) for appending same fields multiple times.So far i am unable to get all the values as i am using jquery and ajax to post these inputs.

---

[image]

```js
$('.myFlag').on('change', function () {

      var flagID = $(".myFlag option:selected").val();
alert(flagID);
});
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
var flag_attach = $('.InputFile')[0].files[0].name;
alert(flag_attach);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-6">
            <div class="row group" >
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Choose Flag Type</label>
                        <select class="form-control myFlag" name="flag_name[]">
                            <option value="">Select Flag</option>
                                <option value="1">A</option>
                                 <option value="2">B</option>
                                  <option value="3">C</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control myFlag" name="flag_name[]">
                            <option value="">Select Flag</option>
                                <option value="1">A</option>
                                 <option value="2">B</option>
                                  <option value="3">C</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Flag</label>
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input InputFile" name="flag_attach[]" id="InputFile" accept="application/pdf">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
<label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Flag</label>
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input InputFile" name="flag_attach[]"  accept="application/pdf">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>
                
                <!-- <div class="col-md-2"></div> --> 
            <!-- </div> -->
           </div>
           <button type="button" id="submit">submit </button>
```

Comment: here `var flagID = $("#flag_id option:selected").val();  ` you are using `id` to get value, so only the first instance of id is taken, either use class or create a snippet and explain the logic you need to implement

Comment: @AkhilAravind i have updated the question please have a look. Unfortunately i couldnt find any cdn link for Jquery Multifield plugin to add into snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below snippet with jquery-multifield plugin enabled. Here you can add files and on submit, the filled data can be seen in console. Please use browser console for clear view.

Here form data is assigned to `_form` variable, you need to send this variable to server.

```js
$('.myFlag').on('change', function() {
  var flagID = $(this).val();
});
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
  var _form = new FormData(this);// get the form object values. Send this variable to ajax call.
  for (var value of _form.values()) {
    console.log(value); // shows each form values. here you can see the file name etc...
  }
});
$('#example-6').multifield({
  section: '.section',
  btnAdd: '.btnAdd',
  btnRemove: '.btnRemove'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxkostinevich.github.io/jquery-multifield/jquery.multifield.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="example-6">
      <div class="row group">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnAdd">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Choose Flag Type</label>
              <select class="form-control myFlag" name="flag_name[]">
                <option value="">Select Flag</option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Flag</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input InputFile" name="flag_attach[]" accept="application/pdf">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btnRemove" type="button">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank your for working on it. Its working in your snippet exactly the way i want, but i am not getting all file inputs in my original code. It shows only the first file. Please see this https://codepen.io/haro0n/pen/gOpWbmW

Comment: @HaroonKhan why dont you follow the exact mark up from the answer, and also your javascript are messed, everything is clearly written in the snippet. Follow it. :)

Comment: i can not use the exact code that you provided, because for some reason i dont get flag_attachment input without using formdata.append();

Comment: @HaroonKhan may I know for what are you using it ??

Comment: The entire scenario is obviously different as i have many others inputs to deal with in my form. please have a look at codepen, any further help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want, IMHO i think the entire scenario is covered, and may I know for what `var flag_attach = $('.InputFile')[0].files[0];
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('flag_attach[]',flag_attach);` this is called ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208634/discussion-between-haroon-khan-and-akhil-aravind).